# move with the keyboard arrows through the items of 2 recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 recyclerviews and I want to move in the view through their items, changing the background color of the item that is selected and change the recyclerview with the TAB key and the focus does not leave the recycledview until the TAB key is pressed.
this is my XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/clcontenido"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/estados_totales"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textcomandassiges">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="#CDCDCD"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rv1"
        >
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="#CDCDCD"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I manage it with 2 adapters which are these

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
rv_pendientes = findViewById(R.id.rv1);
        rv_atenciones = findViewById(R.id.rv2);

        rv_pendientes.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(rv_pendientes.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        rv_atenciones.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(rv_atenciones.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        rv_pendientes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        rv_atenciones.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        adapter_pendientes = new Adapter_pendientes(lista_pendientes);
        adapter_atenciones = new Adapter_atenciones(lista_atenciones);

        adapter_pendientes.actualizarAlturaElemento(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        adapter_atenciones.actualizarAlturaElemento(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        rv_pendientes.setAdapter(adapter_pendientes);
        rv_atenciones.setAdapter(adapter_atenciones);

        rv_pendientes.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv_atenciones.setHasFixedSize(true);

        rv_atenciones.requestFocus();


rv_pendientes.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB:
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "Presionaste TAB 2");
                            if (adapter_atenciones.getItemCount() > 0) {
                                adapter_atenciones.setSelectedPosition(0); // Establece la posición seleccionada en el adaptador2
                                adapter_atenciones.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notifica al adaptador2 que los datos han cambiado
                                rv_atenciones.scrollToPosition(0);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"entro 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// Mueve el foco al primer elemento en rv2
                            }
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                            if (adapter_pendientes.selectedPosition_pendientes > 0) {
                                adapter_pendientes.selectedPosition_pendientes--;
                                rv_pendientes.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter_pendientes.selectedPosition_pendientes);
                                adapter_pendientes.notifyItemChanged(adapter_pendientes.selectedPosition_pendientes);
                            }
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:

                            adapter_pendientes.selectedPosition_pendientes++;
                            rv_pendientes.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter_pendientes.selectedPosition_pendientes);
                            adapter_pendientes.notifyItemChanged(adapter_pendientes.selectedPosition_pendientes);

                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        rv_atenciones.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB:
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "Presionaste TAB");
                            if (adapter_pendientes.getItemCount() > 0) {
                                adapter_pendientes.setSelectedPosition(0); // Establece la posición seleccionada en el adaptador2

                                rv_pendientes.scrollToPosition(0);
                                adapter_pendientes.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"entro",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// Mueve el foco al primer elemento en rv2
                            }
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                            if (adapter_atenciones.selectedPosition_atenciones > 0) {
                                adapter_atenciones.selectedPosition_atenciones--;
                                rv_atenciones.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter_atenciones.selectedPosition_atenciones);
                                adapter_atenciones.notifyItemChanged(adapter_atenciones.selectedPosition_atenciones);
                            }
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:

                                adapter_atenciones.selectedPosition_atenciones++;
                                rv_atenciones.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter_atenciones.selectedPosition_atenciones);
                                adapter_atenciones.notifyItemChanged(adapter_atenciones.selectedPosition_atenciones);

                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

}

private class Adapter_pendientes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_pendientes.ViewHolder> {
        private List<String> data;
        private int selectedPosition_pendientes = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

        private int alturaElemento = GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
            selectedPosition_pendientes = position;
        }
        public Adapter_pendientes(List<String> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_comandas, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        public void actualizarAlturaElemento(int nuevaAltura) {
            alturaElemento = nuevaAltura;
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notifica al adaptador que los datos han cambiado.
        }

        private int getScreenWidth() {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            return displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.textView_pendientes.setText(data.get(position));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams parametros = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    /*width*/ RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    /*height*/ RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            //parametros.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            holder.textView_pendientes.setLayoutParams(parametros);

            //filas = preferences.getInt("filas", 1);
            //ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            //layoutParams.height = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; // Establece la altura dinámica aquí
            //holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            int color = 0;
            String estado = listaestado_pendientes.get(position);
            //Log.e("COLOR-ESTADO: ",estado);
            switch (estado) {
                case "1":
                    color = colorpendientes_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: PENDIENTES ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
                case "2":
                    color = coloratenciones_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: ATENCIONES ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
                case "3":
                    color = colorentregables_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: ENTREGABLE ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
                case "4":
                    color=colorentregadas_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: ENTREGADO ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
                case "X":
                    color=coloranuladas_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: ANULADA ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
            }


            boolean modificado = listamodifica_pendientes.get(position);
            if (layout_historico==false){
                if (modificado == true) {
                    holder.textViewmodificado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.textViewmodificado, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f);
                    //alphaAnimator.setDuration(1000); // Duración de un segundo
                    //alphaAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
                    //alphaAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);

                    // Inicia la animación
                    //alphaAnimator.start();
                } else {
                    holder.textViewmodificado.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                holder.textViewmodificado.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                holder.textViewmodificado.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            ttexto_remoto = preferences.getInt("ttexto", 14);
            holder.textView_pendientes.setTextColor(colortexto_remoto);
            holder.textView_pendientes.setTextSize(ttexto_remoto);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(color);

            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
            if (position == selectedPosition_pendientes) {
                holder.textView_pendientes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_border_comanda);
                //holder.textViewmodificado.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_border);
            } else {
                holder.textView_pendientes.setBackgroundResource(0);
                //holder.textViewmodificado.setBackgroundResource(0);
            }
            int screenWidth = getScreenWidth();
            int itemWidth = screenWidth / 5; // Divide el ancho de la pantalla por 5 para mostrar 5 elementos por fila
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = itemWidth;
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView textView_pendientes;
            TextView textViewmodificado;
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView_pendientes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewcomandas);
                textViewmodificado = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewmodificado);
                //TextSizeAdjuster.adjustTextSizeBasedOnScreenSize(MainActivity.this, textView_pendientes);
                textView_pendientes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int previousSelectedPosition = selectedPosition_pendientes;
                        selectedPosition_pendientes = getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();

                        // Notifica el cambio en la posición seleccionada para actualizar la vista
                        notifyItemChanged(previousSelectedPosition);
                        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition_pendientes);
                        showAlertDialog(selectedPosition_pendientes);
                        //oast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hiciste clic"+selectedPosition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }

    private class Adapter_atenciones extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_atenciones.ViewHolder> {
        private List<String> data;
        private int selectedPosition_atenciones = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

        private int alturaElemento = GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
            selectedPosition_atenciones = position;
        }
        public Adapter_atenciones(List<String> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_comandas, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        public void actualizarAlturaElemento(int nuevaAltura) {
            alturaElemento = nuevaAltura;
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notifica al adaptador que los datos han cambiado.
        }

        private int getScreenWidth() {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            return displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.textView_atenciones.setText(data.get(position));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams parametros = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    /*width*/ RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    /*height*/ RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            //parametros.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            holder.textView_atenciones.setLayoutParams(parametros);

            //filas = preferences.getInt("filas", 1);
            //ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            //layoutParams.height = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; // Establece la altura dinámica aquí
            //holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            int color = 0;
            String estado = listaestado_atenciones.get(position);
            //Log.e("COLOR-ESTADO: ",estado);
            switch (estado) {
                case "1":
                    color = colorpendientes_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: PENDIENTES ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
                case "2":
                    color = coloratenciones_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: ATENCIONES ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
                case "3":
                    color = colorentregables_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: ENTREGABLE ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
                case "4":
                    color=colorentregadas_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: ENTREGADO ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
                case "X":
                    color=coloranuladas_remoto;
                    Log.e("COLOR: ANULADA ", String.valueOf(color));
                    break;
            }


            boolean modificado = listamodifica_atenciones.get(position);
            if (layout_historico==false){
                if (modificado == true) {
                    holder.textViewmodificado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.textViewmodificado, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f);
                    //alphaAnimator.setDuration(1000); // Duración de un segundo
                    //alphaAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
                    //alphaAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);

                    // Inicia la animación
                    //alphaAnimator.start();
                } else {
                    holder.textViewmodificado.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                holder.textViewmodificado.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                holder.textViewmodificado.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            ttexto_remoto = preferences.getInt("ttexto", 14);
            holder.textView_atenciones.setTextColor(colortexto_remoto);
            holder.textView_atenciones.setTextSize(ttexto_remoto);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(color);

            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
            if (position == selectedPosition_atenciones) {
                holder.textView_atenciones.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_border_comanda);
                //holder.textViewmodificado.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_border);
            } else {
                holder.textView_atenciones.setBackgroundResource(0);
                //holder.textViewmodificado.setBackgroundResource(0);
            }
            int screenWidth = getScreenWidth();
            int itemWidth = screenWidth / 5; // Divide el ancho de la pantalla por 5 para mostrar 5 elementos por fila
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = itemWidth;
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView textView_atenciones;
            TextView textViewmodificado;
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView_atenciones = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewcomandas);
                textViewmodificado = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewmodificado);
                //TextSizeAdjuster.adjustTextSizeBasedOnScreenSize(MainActivity.this, textView_pendientes);
                textView_atenciones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int previousSelectedPosition = selectedPosition_atenciones;
                        selectedPosition_atenciones = getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();

                        // Notifica el cambio en la posición seleccionada para actualizar la vista
                        notifyItemChanged(previousSelectedPosition);
                        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition_atenciones);
                        showAlertDialog(selectedPosition_atenciones);
                        //oast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hiciste clic"+selectedPosition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
```

it only cycles through the top recyclerview fine but the bottom one doesn't.

change the focus of the recyclerview with the TAB key and scroll through its items with the keyboard arrows